# PHPDocumentor, phpdoc - missing file-level and global variable comments; 'alse' and 'rue'

Tags: phpdoc, docblocks, phpdocumentor2, docblox

I am a newbie to phpDocumentor, although I have extensively used JavaDoc in the past.

To start, I created the following test file **a.php**:

```
<?php
  /**
   * XYZ file-level comment.
   */

  /**
   * XYZ global variable comment.
   *
   * @var int
   */
  $var = 123;

  /**
   * XYZ constant comment.
   *
   * @var boolean
   */
  const DO_IT = false;

?>
```

And then I ran **phpDocumentor v3.0.0** using the following commandline:

```
php D:\phpDocumentor\phpDocumentor.phar
```

The resulting documentation has the following issues - see a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfoa0.png):

1. Neither file-level comment nor global variable $var are present in the generated HTML.
2. For constant DO_IT, the first letter of the default value is missing ('alse').

Any idea what might I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem :(